# Should I use asterisks or dashes for bullets in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I have noticed that asterisks (`*`) and dashes (`-`) both generate bullets in Markdown. Is there a preferred symbol to use or does it really not matter?

With Bullets:

[image]

[image]

With Dashes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For creating unorderd lists you can use `*` or `+` or `-`. Which one you use, doesn't really matter. But you should keep it consistent. Ie chose the one symbol you like most and stick with it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference. Your Markdown may become more readable if you chose one of these for each level, e.g.

```
- first level

  * second level

- first level again
```

But other than that, it's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of resources that state `*`, `+`, `-` can all be used interchangeably.

- [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) John Gruber - originator of markdown ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown))
- [Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#unordered-lists)
- [Github Flavoured Markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#lists) (GFM) - A common de-facto standard
- [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/help/) - unofficial base standard for other flavours of markdown
- [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/8.7-lists.html)

While I'm not aware of any officially recognised standards organisation defining what markdown should look like, and there are many, many flavours, these resources are a good starting point for what is commonly allowable.

Where you might get some restrictions is from linters that attempt to enforce some consistency in usage like [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/md004.md) for vscode. This suggests top-level lists use an asterisk `*` and that that different characters are used for sub-levels:

```
* Item 1
  + Item 2
    - Item 3
  + Item 4
* Item 4
  + Item 5
```